# Java Swing GridLayout "Cell span"?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

Is there a way to make a single element in a Grid layout take up more than 1 location in a grid.  Example:  I want to create a textbox that takes up an entire grid row, is there some way to do this?

Comment: [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) and the answer is *no*.

Comment: Alternatively, nest multiple panels having `GridLayout` to achieve a comparable effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) instead.